# Random Number Generator Cofirmation

Tags: c++, random, srand

I just wanted to know if the following code actually include the value 3.0? (I know rand() is not the best, but I just wanted to try this out)

```
//function returns random double value between specificed range, inclusively.
double randomDouble (double minVal, double maxVal) {
    return double(rand()) / RAND_MAX * (maxVal - minVal) + minVal;
}
```

My logic was that

1. double(rand()) / RAND_MAX gives random numbers in range 0.0 to 1.0, inclusive
2. (maxVal - minVal) then turns that into 0.0 to MaxVal, inclusive
3. adding minVal finally gives us random double values from minVal to maxVal, inclusive.

So, I tried to test if they really include maxVal by running this code:

```
int cnt = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 999999999; i++) {
    if (randomDouble(1.0, 3.0) == 3.0) {
        cnt++;
    }
}
cout << cnt << endl;
```

But the cnt was zero always.

So I wasn't sure if my function was right?

Comment: Use [std::uniform_real_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) and forget about `rand()`.

Comment: Oh i have to use rand() for this specific question.

Comment: *So I wasn't sure if my function was right?* -- You should print out or record the actual values you *are* getting so that you can get an idea of what your function is producing.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you i'll try that

Comment: Then do I have to add +1.0 to RAND_MAX then divide?

Comment: No, your and my tests are invalid. 999999999 is 2.15 times less than 2147483647, thus it meets 2147483647 with a chance less than 1/2.

Comment: Adding 1 to RANDMAX would be going the wrong direction.  I've always known RAND_MAX to be *included* in the output anyway.  But hitting it exactly is going to be very rare.

Comment: so my function is correct? It's just that it's really rare to hit the RAND_MAX or in this case maxVal, right

Comment: yes, you can verify that by replacing `rand()` with `RAND_MAX` and seeing the output ..... beware that `cout` and `printf` will approximate the result before printing .... so you have to look at the binary representation to verify that.

Comment: @roundofferror -- There is no guarantee that *any* value that you choose will show up.  If instead of `3`, what would be the chance of say, `2.000234`, showing up?  I could see if you had a range of integers between 1 and 1000000 or something like that, and you wanted to generate random numbers, but floating point is a different story.  It's just that you conveniently chose `3` as your test, because that's what shows up in your question as the upper limit.

Comment: @roundofferror -- Also, your way of testing if a value was `3.0` is flawed, all because of floating point not being exact and using `==` for comparisons.  [Look at this code](https://godbolt.org/z/5a6jcc6bW).  It does what your code is doing, but records the values in a `std::set<double>`.  If you see what is printed out, it gives the illusion that `1` and `3` are indeed the min and max values found, but a closer look you will see that it is not exactly 1 or exactly 3 (the last two `cout` statements).  Also, note that `cnt` is still 0, even though `3` was "generated" (but not actually `3`).

Comment: And ironically, your name of `roundofferror` basically fits what is going on in the example.

Comment: bahha that's true. yeah glad to know that my logic was flawed.

Comment: 1.0/RAND_MAX produces a double that is only an approximation. Thus multiples of it will also be approximations and not match exact numbers like 3.0 unless you get lucky.

Answer (score 2):

The only way your function could return `maxVal` is when `rand()` returns exactly `RAND_MAX`.  That's going to be exceedingly rare, testing 999999999 times may not be enough to hit it.

Comment: gotcha. so there's no mathematical error within in my function?

Comment: @roundofferror I didn't see one, although it depends on whether `RAND_MAX` is included in `rand()` output or not.  In my experience it is but I don't remember what the specs say.

Comment: `RAND_MAX` is the maximum value returned by `rand()`. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX).